# Fazer inclusões do respectivo usuário Laravel 5.5 Auth Padrão

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, autenticação, auth

Tenho uma dúvida simples, estou montando alguns cadastros com finalidade de estudo do framework laravel, com Pessoas, Plano de contas e etc..

Estou utilizando a autenticação padrão do Laravel, e agora me deparei com a seguinte situação, os cadastros de pessoas, e todos lançamentos de contas a pagar e receber que eu cadastrei por um respectivo usuário esta visível para outros também.. Acredito que seja pq estou usando o método **Fornecedores::all();** etc.. O que devo fazer para retornar apenas os Fornecedores que foi cadastrado por este respectivo usuário para que não seja visível por todos

Comment: Dentro da tabelas tem um campo destinado a gravar o id do usuário que gravou aquele registro?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Eu estava verificando isto agora! Eu apenas preciso ter o ID do user no cadastro de pessoas, que as outras tabelas já estão relacionadas, mas no PessoaController@store eu estou utilizando o request->all(), como faço para apenas o campo id_user ser preenchido automaticamente com o id do respectivo usuário logado?

Comment: Auto::user()->id seria isso

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Ficaria assim $pessoa = Pessoa::create($request->all(Auto::user()->id));

Comment: Dentro da tabela pessoa tem o campo user id ou equivalente?

Comment: Sim, acabei de modificar, inseri uma coluna user_id como chave estrangeira do id da tabela user, e já configurei o hasMany e BelongsTo

Comment: Fornecedores::where('user_id',  Auth::user()->id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode colocar em sua controller no método store o usuario logado. por exemplo:

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

$pessoa = Pessoa::create($data);
```

E quando for buscar os fornecedores que pertencem a pessoa, você pode fazer dessa maneira:

```
$fornecedores = App\Fornecedor::with(['pessoa' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
}])->get();
```